# Is PartitionAware supported on Hazelcast's IMap values?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Like described in a title I want my `IMap` values to implement `PartitionAware<T>` interface. Does Hazelcast support that or are the `IMap` keys the only one that should implement it?

For instance I have `IMap<Long, MyValueClass>` where `MyValueClass implements PartitionAware<SomeCustomObject>`. Will Hazelcast respect `PartitionAware` on values and put all entries with same `SomeCustomObject` on same partition (assume that `SomeCustomObject` has `equals` and `hashCode` methods impemented)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition to store the entry is based on the key.

For example, `IMap.get(K)` only has access to the key, the value is unknown before the retrieval call.
If the key didn't dictate the partition, all partitions would have to be scanned to find the entry.

A key can be a compound, eg. `IMap<Tuple2<Long, Long>, SomeCustomObject>`. Here the key is a pair of numbers, partition placement could be based on either or both.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was hoping that was not the case. I now have to replace current key (Long), which represents id of the MyValueClass, with new object that will implement PartitionAware and keep this id inside. Which means that in order to access the value by key, I have to have all the data to create the actual key or index `__key.id` and access value with predicate which is not ideal at all...